# VSCode open file dialog is not showing the current directory of the current active file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I updated VSCode yesterday then the problem showed (**It shows the last opened file directory** regardless of the working directory)

I'm using VSCode for long time and it was OK with this feature, can I customize it in settings or this feature has been removed.

I think opening current active file directory in the dialog explorer is very useful at least for me

Comment: Press Alt+ctrl+R and click on file in vscode explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was addressed on vscode github. There will be a fix: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/151668